# passing data from view to view laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, view, laravel-5.3

i have a page called `drivers.blade.php` in which i'm displaying only few fields from database 
and i have a `view-more-link` on clicking that the user should go to `driver-details`

where i'm displaying all the details of the `driver`, it's some thing like product and product-detail page

My drivers.blade.php

```
@foreach($drivers as $driver)

<div class="col s12 m6 l3">
<div class="card small card-driver">
    <div class="card-image">
        <img src="assets/images/profile-image-2.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
        <div class="card-details">
            <p>Name:</p><span>{{ $driver->first_name }} &nbsp; {{ $driver->last_name }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-details">
            <p>Phone:</p><span>{{ $driver->phone_number }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-details">
            <p>Address:</p>
            <span>
                {{ $driver->address_city_village }} &nbsp; {{ $driver->address_state }}
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-action">
        <a href="driver-details" class="waves-effect waves-light btn green">View Details</a> //onclick go to that perticular driver details by passinf id
    </div>
</div>
</div>

@endforeach
```

My Controller is DriverController.php

```
public function getDrivers() 
{
    $drivers = Driver::all();

    return view('drivers', compact('drivers'));
}

public function getDriverDetails($id) 
{
    $driver = Driver::find($id);

    if(! $driver) {
        return $this->respondNotFound();
    }

    return view('drivers-details', compact('driver'));

}
```

if i go to the `http://localhost:8000/driver-details` page i'm getting the following error

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

My Routes are

```
Route::resource('drivers', 'DriversController@getDrivers');
Route::resource('drivers-details', 'DriversController@getDriverDetails');
```

Looking forward for much needed help

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Route::resource` is for CRUD only. if you are not using `[index, create, store, show, edit, update, destroy]` methods then you should not use `Route::resource` instead there are many other ways like `Route::get`, `Route::post`, etc.

It is because you are using --

```
Route::get('drivers-details', 'DriversController@getDriverDetails');
```

and requesting for `http://localhost:8000/driver-details` which is not registered inside the routes, if you visit  `http://localhost:8000/drivers-details` you will not get the error.

In your controller, `getDriverDetails($id)`, you gave a parameter, to use it you need to register it to your routes to use it like this --

```
Route::get('drivers-details/{id}', 'DriversController@getDriverDetails');
```

you also need to send the id to the url norder to access it --

```
<a href="/drivers-details/{{ $driver->id }}" class="waves-effect waves-light btn green">View Details</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

You are trying for http://localhost:8000/**driver-details** while your route is for **drivers-details**.

Comment: but now i'm getting this error, on http://localhost:8000/driver-details

`ErrorException in DriversController.php line 142:
Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\DriversController::getDriverDetails()`
if i add the driver id http://localhost:8000/driver-details/1 my view will load up without css and js, i guess because og the /1

how do i pass the id of the driver from drivers page to driver-details page and get the driver details based on that id

thank you

Comment: you have to set that also in route. change your route to Route::resource('drivers-details/{pid}', 'DriversController@getDriverDetails'); and in controller add a parameter in  the function. like getDriverDetails($pid)

Comment: thanks for your time, but how do i pass the id of driver from `driver` page to `driver-details` page and get the details of that page

Comment: i referenced `id` in route i'm getting this error `Route pattern "/driver-details/{id}/{{id}}" cannot reference variable name "id" more than once.`

Comment: add one time only driver-details/{id}. if multiple parameter then add another one but with different name

Answer (score 1):

Try this route

```
Route::resource('drivers-detail', 'DriversController@getDriverDetails');
```